# Handling class specific properties in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm still wrapping my head around generics and have run up against a challenge that I want to work through correctly.  If I have a few classes defined like so:

```
public abstract class DocBase {
    public long ID { get; set; }                                    
    public string Description { get; set; }             
    public long DocumentID { get; set; }                
    public string DocumentDate { get; set; }            
    ...snipped...
}

public class AppDoc : DocBase {
    public string A { get; set; }                                    
    public string B { get; set; }             
    public string C { get; set; }                    
}

public class OtherDoc : DocBase {
    public string D { get; set; }                                    
    public string E { get; set; }             
    public string F { get; set; }                    
}
```

I have a class that will be used to retrieve these documents

```
public class Repo<T> where T : DocBase, new()
```

This class will contain a method:

```
public List<T> GetDocs()
```

In this method I want to be able to access the properties defined in the derived classes (so in AppDoc: A,B,C and in OtherDoc: D,E,F).  But if I declare a new object like so:

```
var doc = new T();
```

At design time I only have the properties available in the base class (DocBase) and not the dervied classes (AppDoc and OtherDoc).  How do I get to properties A, B, C, D, E and F?

EDIT: To elaborate on my "how do I get to..." a bit.  I need to populate properties A, B, C, D, E and F within the GetDocs() method from a list of results I get back from a database.

```
public List<T> GetDocs(){    

var results = someService.GetMyDocuments();
var documents = new List<T>();

    foreach(IRepositoryRow row in results) {
        var newDoc = new T();

        newDoc.A = row.GetProperty("AFromDatabase").ToString();
        newDoc.B = row.GetProperty("BFromDatabase").ToString();

        documents.Add(newDoc);    
    }

    return documents;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what are you wanting to do with those properties.

If you are manipulating them (eg populating them or calculating thigns based on them) then an abstract method on `DocBase` like `DoStuff` could then be called safely on your T and it could do whatever you want with the properties.

If you want to do different things depending on what the object is then that's not really being very generic and you probably want to rethink things a bit, preferably to having abstract or virtual methods that you can call on the objects.

Some sample code based on what you've put in your question:

```
public abstract class DocBase {
    ...
    public abstract void LoadProperties(IRepositoryRow row);
    ...
}

public List<T> GetDocs(){    

    var results = someService.GetMyDocuments();
    var documents = new List<T>();

    foreach(IRepositoryRow row in results) {
        var newDoc = new T();
        newDoc.LoadProperties(row);
        documents.Add(newDoc);    
    }
    return documents;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I just updated the code in the question to show what I plan on doing with the properties.  If I understand what you mean I should create an abstract MapFromDB method on the base class then implement it in both derived classes to accept a IRepositoryRow row and map the properties from the row parameter to the correct properties in each class?

Comment: @Mike: exactly. I've added some sample code in my answer to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Awesome, my solution was identical but for the method name.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The only reason I chose that name is that it felt more descriptive to me. The other option might be to have a factory to make your objects. I'm not sure of a good way to do this with generics sadly but I quite like, when possible, to create objects using a constructor that takes the `IRepositoryRow` object and creates the object based on that. Mainly because my OCD kicks off when I think about the object not being in a valid state between the construction and loading of the properties. :)

Comment: I like the idea of a constructor taking the IRepositoryRow object.  I think I'll give that a go... Of course after doing the legwork on this the other developer I'm working with mentioned that we won't need this to be generic as "the requirements have changed".  :(  Oh well, good mental exercise.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That's generally flawed. Your design would break the laws of polymorphism entirely, because you want access to a a derived class' properties where only base class information is available.

So the question is not *How can I ...* but *What's wrong with my design?*.

**Edit**:
OR Mappers (e.g. Entity Framework or NHibernate) can handle such polymorphism scenarios automatically for you. I suggest you take this route.

Comment: His design isn't that flawed because he has an object of the right type that he can delegate this work to. You are right that he can't (and shouldn't) access the properties in his generic class but he can pass all the information on to the class itself to deal with.

Comment: Well, you solve it by migrating property loading to the concrete instances themselves. In this case, everything is fine of course because here the concrete type information is available. But that does not apply to the sample code as shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks guys after reading Chris' answer, I came up with almost exactly the same code, so I guess I'm getting closer to understanding generics.  I intuitively know what I want to do, but I don't always get the object separation and syntax required for what I want to do.